# MyFramework `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, framework, cocoapods

Tengo una librería para Cocoapods que incluye un xcframework. La definición del podspec es la siguiente:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name                  = 'MySDK'
  s.version               = '1.0.0'
  s.summary               = 'Summary'
  s.description           = 'Description'
  s.homepage              = 'homepage_url'
  s.license               = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author                = { 'xxxxx' => 'xxxxxx' }
  s.source                = { :git => 'xxxxxx' }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '15.0'

  s.source_files          = 'MySDK/**/*.{swift,xcframework}''
  s.vendored_frameworks   = 'MySDK/Frameworks/MyFramework.xcframework'
  s.preserve_paths       = 'MySDK/Frameworks/MyFramework.xcframework'
  s.xcconfig              = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework MyFramework' }
  s.frameworks            = 'UIKit', 'SwiftUI', 'XCTest', 'MyFramework'
  
  s.dependency 'iOSDFULibrary', '~> 4.13.0'

end
```

Cuando valido con *pod lib lint --allow-warnings --no-clean* el resultado es correcto, pasa la validación.

**MySDK passed validation.**

Pero cuando valido con *pod spec lint* recibo este error:

```
-> MySDK (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | file patterns: The `preserve_paths` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - WARN  | [iOS] swift: The validator used Swift `4.0` by default because no Swift version was specified. To specify a Swift version during validation, add the `swift_versions` attribute in your podspec. Note that usage of a `.swift-version` file is now deprecated.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'iOSDFULibrary' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'ZIPFoundation' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Metadata extraction skipped. No AppIntents.framework dependency found. (in target 'ZIPFoundation' from project 'Pods')
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  MySDK/MySDK/MySDK/Classes/Managers/BluetoothStatusManager.swift:11:8: error: no such module 'MyFramework'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Metadata extraction skipped. No AppIntents.framework dependency found. (in target 'iOSDFULibrary' from project 'Pods')

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 4 errors and 2 warnings.
```

Gracias a todos por adelantado!